# Cursor Timed out error on MongoDb cursor

Tags: mongodb

I have just started using mongoDb as my backend for PHP.

I am simply using find() query for one of my needs. I want only first 100 results but also want to get total available results. I am trying this.

```
    $cursor = $this->dbReference->dbName->find($query);
    if($count != 0)
    {
            $cursor->skip($startIndex);
            $cursor->limit($count);
    }
    $totalCount = $cursor->count();

    $entries = array();
    while ($cursor->hasNext())
    {
            $cursor->next();
            $entry = $cursor->current();
            array_push($entries , $entry);
    }
```

Now The problem is.. T
his search result contains exactly more than 50K results. But I am retrieving only 100 at a time.
I am using $cursor->count() for getting total number of available result rows.
on this line error is showing that "Cursor timed out". Please can anyone suggest me whats the problem? or what is the alternative to find total count of search result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: New version of mongodb resolve this issue, And working good with laravel and nodejs

Answer (score 7):

You can solve cursor time out problem by adding this code before `find()`:

```
MongoCursor::$timeout = -1;
$cursor = $this->dbReference->dbName->find($query);
```

Comment: 'MongoCursor::$timeout' static property is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I have just tried this out with 100,000 simple documents. `$totalCount` for me is always 100000, regardless of whether `$count` and `$startIndex` are set (this is the correct behaviour). `$entries` contains all 100000 entries. The whole operation takes about 3 seconds on my local setup.

Are you using a remote database? It's possible the network is what is causing the timeout rather than MongoDB.

What size are your documents? The volume of data can affect the speed.

Comment: @danielwood Yes, I am using remote database , but it is also on local network(Intranet). Might be that problem will be because of $cursor->count(); And also $cursor->count() increases execution time. If I am not using $cursor->count() It is performing fast as u said.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the ->count() also blows out the execution time until it times out. What is better to me is to just use find() and then place the desired item in the cursor into an array using a foreach loop.
After that do an array_count_values() on that array. Seems to be a bit faster too.

Thanks for the MongoCursor::$timeout = -1 for I think it really helped in my situation too.

Magically there are no more horrible timeout messages.